# Kibana fuzz search with quotation mark

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'd like to know how to fuzz search a field with quotation mark in it. I'm actually trying to query like this:

```
message: *\" 500*
```

I expect all logs with message field that contains `" 500` will be filtered as result, but it ignores the `\"` part in fact. How to achieve this?

Comment: Try something like `message: ".*\" 500.*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but the dot makes it worse with empty result.